# How do I enhance a VBA method?

Tags: .net, vba, com, ms-word

I'm trying to open a Word document via HTTP from a remote server. The [Documents.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff835182.aspx) method supports this just fine, as I can pass it a URL as a filename and it loads it from the remote server.

However, in order to get the file, I need to POST credentials to a URL, then follow the location field of the response to get the file. How would I subclass or overload the Documents object to do this step before passing the content to Word to open?

Forgot to mention -- this uses a cookie based authentication, so I need to persist the authenticated cookie between the various HTTP sessions.

Edit #2: Alternately,

If I would get a complete MSXML2.XMLHTTP based subroutine made that would POST the authentication, parse out the set-cookie and location headers from the response, and use those to GET the document content from the server, is there any way I can open the in-memory document as a file instead of dumping temp files out to the filesystem willy-nilly? From reading the docs, Open() just supports a file name (or path).

There's a .NET way to to this with IO.System.MemoryMappedFile, I believe, but is there any way this would be exposed to COM so i could just dump the bytestream into a function, get a filehandle, then pass that to .Open() to handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XMLHTTP to perform the post, then parse the response for the path.  As far as I know though, you cannot override built-in methods like .Open()

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/991125.htm

Half-way down that page there's a POST example in VBA

Tim

Comment: Knew I was forgetting something -- I could get the URL that way, but the process of POSTing the authentication sets a cookie that is then used to access the file's URL. If the cookie's not set, it'll just require authentication again. Is there any way to force headers upon the HTTP request the built in .Open() method uses?

Comment: I don't know what headers Word sends when it opens a document over HTTP, and whether or not they include cookies.  You can always check using Fiddler or similar.  Worst case, you could perform a GET on the URL, again using xmlhttp, and save the document to the temp directory.